# Tricky Entity Framework one to one relationship

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, mapping, code-first

I have an app which records entries into different events of tennis tournaments. It also records who the winner was of each event

The 2 classes in question are:

```
public class Event {
  public int EventId { get; set; }
  public string EventName { get; set; }
  public virtual ICollection<Entry> Entries { get; set; }
  public int? WinningEntryId { get; set; }

  [ForeignKey("WinningEntryId")]
  public virtual Entry WinningEntry { get; set; }
}

public class Entry {
  public int EntryId { get; set; }
  public int EventId { get; set; }

  [ForeignKey("EventId")]
  public virtual Event Event { get; set; }
}
```

Note that the Event.WinningEntryId column is nullable as I don't want to have to specify the winner as the tournament may still be in progress.

Now, the problem is that when I run the Update-Database command, it generates the following tables:

```
Entry
 - EntryId
 - EventId
 - Event_EventId

Event
 - EventId
 - WinningEntryId
```

Why is EF generating the Event_EventId column in the Event table? I simply want the Event.WinningEntryId column to point to the Entry.EntryId column in a foreign key relationship.

I must be doing this wrong somehow. Anybody know how I can accomplish this?

Comment: This code won't compile as your navigation and foreign key properties are both called WinningEntryId

Comment: Yes, sorry that was a typo! Fixed now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that your navigation property:

```
public virtual Entry WinningEntryId { get; set; }
```

is actually called `WinningEntry`:

```
public virtual Entry WinningEntry { get; set; }
```

then actually it looks like you're modelling a one-to-many relationship, not a one-to-one. An event can have many entries, and an entry can belong to one event? It's just that one of those entries will be marked as the winning entry.

I would consider not using data annotations, and sticking with the fluent API for a) management of all of your configuration in a central place and b) not mixing persistence concerns with your domain objects.

In which case, you could configure your mappings using the fluent API as such:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{     
    modelBuilder.Entity<Event>()
       .HasOptional(ev => ev.WinningEntry)
       .WithMany()
       .HasForeignKey(ev => ev.WinningEntryId)
       .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

    modelBuilder.Entity<Entry>()
        .HasRequired(en => en.Event)
        .WithMany(ev => ev.Entries)
        .HasForeignKey(en => en.EventId);
}
```

This will model the relationship with:

```
Events
    EventId (PK)
    EventName
    WinningEventId (FK, null)

Entries
    EntryId (PK)
    EventId (FK, not null)
```

Comment: Worked a charm! Thanks a lot. I haven't really looked much into the Fluent API. Do you know of any good resources to learn from? I found the MSDN entry to be rather basic.

Comment: I would buy Julia Lerman's two books on code first - Programming Entity Framework Code First, and Programming Entity Framework DbContext.

Answer (score 1):

The marked answer accomplishes what you need to do but the real reason as to why you were getting `Event_EventId` in your table is because of this:

```
public virtual ICollection<Entry> Entries { get; set; }
```

Noted in your Event entity. Which simply means that an Event is a collection of similar Entries. And by that logic, creates a one-to-many relationship between Event and Entry.

**-Event has many Entries**

**-Entry belongs to one Event**

Therefore, Each Entry must have foreign key `Event_EventId` to state which Event the Entry belongs to.